# Fetching all the paths between two nodes using gremlin in java

Tags: java, graph-databases, orientdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

Hi I am kinda new to gremlin and trying to achieve some solve by finding all the paths between two nodes. In simple query on gremlin console I was able to do that using this query :

```
(Name of the first Node).loop(1){it.loops<100}{true}.has('name', (Name of the second node)).path{it.name}
```

But while I was trying to fetch that from java methods I am into sea of problems, like:

-- no clue on where to put the query exactly ?
-- what data structure will be right to receive the array of rows.
-- how to collect the first node and second node from the graph.

Here I have tried to proceed with this, but no clue :

```
  Graph g = new OrientGraph(AppConstants.GRAPH_LOCATION);
         List<String> vertexList = new ArrayList<String>();
         try{
             for (Vertex v : g.getVertices()) {
                    String vertexName = v.getProperty("name");
                    vertexList.add(vertexName);
                }    
             return vertexList;
         } catch (final Exception ex) {
             throw new AppSystemException(ex);
         }finally{
             g.shutdown();
```

Thanks,
Sagir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doesn't make much sense to me, but the description helps. Here's an example, using TinkerGraph, to find all paths between `marko` and `lop`:

```
final Graph g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph();
List<List> names = new ArrayList<>();
new GremlinPipeline<Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>>(g).V().has("name", "marko").as("x").out().loop("x",
        new PipeFunction<LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean compute(LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex> loopBundle) {
                return loopBundle.getLoops() < 100;
            }
        }, new PipeFunction<LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex>, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean compute(LoopPipe.LoopBundle<Vertex> loopBundle) {
                return "lop".equals(loopBundle.getObject().getProperty("name"));
            }
        }
).has("name", "lop").path(new PipeFunction<Vertex, String>() {
    @Override
    public String compute(final Vertex vertex) {
        return vertex.getProperty("name");
    }
}).fill(names);
```

The `names` list will then be filled with the following 2 entries:

1. [marko, lop]
2. [marko, josh, lop]

If converting Groovy to Java is the biggest problem, you should definitely check this out: [Converting Gremlin Groovy to Gremlin Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409219/gremlinpipeline-java-api-chain-traversal-in-titan-graph-use-cases/29411662#29411662)

Comment: As far as "where your query goes" and "how to collect the data" - your "query" that's in the console is really just an `Iterator` - simply treat it as such in your java code.  You could also create a groovy-based library with graph traversals in it.  Then reference that from your java library.  Or simply have your groovy graph traversal co-exist in `.groovy` files with your `.java` files.  It's pretty easy to have a mixed project.

Comment: Can you please mension what would be the value for as("x")  and   .out() and .loop("x" ...  ??
I mean x = ?

Comment: `x` is the vertex where your looped traversal traversal starts from. In my example for the 2nd path it's `marko` in the first loop and `josh` in the second loop. It's basically the same as `.loop(1)`, but it uses a named step instead of a number of steps.

Comment: Hi Daniel, the reply was greatly helpful. But what I am facing for a graph database which is having more than 10k nodes are not good with this loop. Can you please refer similar query without the loop ... 

Is it right ? g.v(100).out.loop(1) { it.object != g.v(200) }.path   ?

Comment: having a issue where "marko" and "lop" is replaced by two String variable. it is giving blank array return !

Comment: I don't know, maybe provide a Gist that contains the code you're trying to execute.