# Gremlin query which find paths (with node and edges properties) in between two nodes

Tags: java, groovy, playframework, orientdb, gremlin

Need all the nodes & edges properties between two nodes. What I am trying ? I am trying to get all the information of the path between two nodes. Currently I am being able to achieve all node names in between two nodes. But there is some performance issue as there are large transaction that query is not working and giving:

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor, but interface was expected]
```

two specific problem :

1. need all the properties the path in between two nodes. properties like other node names and their edge names.
2. there is some performance issue as when there is some nodes traversal count increases.

[Related : [query]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212204/fetching-all-the-paths-between-two-nodes-using-gremlin-in-java/30215469#30215469)

Comment: What is your query and how large is your graph?

Comment: Hi stephen, I have added query link in the question !

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing because you are showing a class compatibility error but also asking about performance.  Perhaps try to sort out the issue with asm (probably need to exclude a version somewhere in your build) first and then edit your question to be more specific about your performance problems.