# How to use "AND" condition in GremlinPipeLine

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop-blueprint

Suppose I have a list of vertices **Person** with attributes **name** and **age**.I want to write a query that results in a vertex with `name="John" and age=22`.

```
Pipe pipe = (Pipe) new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("name", "John");
Pipe pipe2=new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("age", "22");
List<Vertex>  verList = (List<Vertex>) new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().and(pipe,pipe2).toList();
```

I dont know if this is the correct way to implement it.It is throwing the below exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Graph
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.GraphQueryPipe.processNextStart(GraphQueryPipe.java:33)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.GraphQueryPipe.processNextStart(GraphQueryPipe.java:17)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:89)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.IdentityPipe.processNextStart(IdentityPipe.java:19)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.hasNext(AbstractPipe.java:98)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.Pipeline.hasNext(Pipeline.java:105)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.HasNextPipe.processNextStart(HasNextPipe.java:36)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.transform.HasNextPipe.processNextStart(HasNextPipe.java:16)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:89)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.filter.AndFilterPipe.processNextStart(AndFilterPipe.java:35)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.AbstractPipe.next(AbstractPipe.java:89)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.Pipeline.next(Pipeline.java:115)
at com.tinkerpop.pipes.util.PipeHelper.fillCollection(PipeHelper.java:52)
at com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.GremlinPipeline.toList(GremlinPipeline.java:1564)
at BulkLoad_New.search(BulkLoad_New.java:320)
at BulkLoad_New.main(BulkLoad_New.java:71)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's much need for use of `and` step here.  Just pipeline both `has` conditions:

```
g.V.has('name','John').has('age',22)
```

That's effectively an AND operation.  In Java I guess this would be:

```
new GremlinPipeline(graph).V().has("name", "John").has("age",22);
```

Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29411662/1831717) on how to convert from groovy to java for more information on that topic.

Comment: In which scenario do we exactly use `and`? @stephen

Comment: For more complex conditions where you might traverse away from the currently evaluated element, like: `g.V.and(_().outE('knows'),_().out('likes').has('type','toys'))`